# Draw background of custom View from .png file on Android

Tags: android, view, background, paint, android-canvas

I created a custom View by extending from View. In onDraw() I managed to draw some circles and other stuff. But now I want to add a background from a resource (sd card or a stream) which is actually a map I download from our server and than draw on it. It's for Android 8+

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Canvas g = canvas;
    String file = "/mnt/sdcard/download/tux.png";
    Bitmap bg = null;
    try {
        bg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
        g.setBitmap(bg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MyGraphics", "setBitmap() failed according to debug");
    }
}
```

Somehow g.setBitmap(bg) keeps failing, I haven't looked at the image specs, but actually it's just a tux image (no 24 bits colors) of PNG format.
Can someone give me some tips how to add a background image so I can draw on it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually don't want to draw *on to* the bitmap you load, you just want to draw it on the Canvas, so you should use Canvas.drawBitmap(). You also really should not load a Bitmap in each onDraw(), do it in the constructor instead. Try this class:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomView extends View {
    private final Bitmap mBitmapFromSdcard;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mBitmapFromSdcard = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/download/tux.png");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Canvas g = canvas;
        if (mBitmapFromSdcard != null) {
            g.drawBitmap(mBitmapFromSdcard, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also let Android draw the bitmap in the background:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomView extends View {
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/download/tux.png");
        if (bm != null) {
            setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bm));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Martin,
Thank you very much for this clear example. Strange enough I already did your first example and somehow it didn't work! That's where I started to get lost. The second one is stretching to fit in real estate of the view, that's exactly what had finally. But your first one I like it much better, this way I can position the picture without modifying its size.

Comment: When you try my first example, exactly what does not work? An exception (if so, what exception)? Nothing gets drawn on the screen? What Android version are you running on? Can you provide the exact code you use that you expect to work but that doesn't?

Comment: It does work my friend, with .png as well as .jpg. After your post I was still playing and trying some pictures out and found out that not all .jpeg files work. When I use small jpg pictures like 50 KB it works, but when using bigger jpg pictures like 600 KB the background turns completely white. I don't know whether it has to do with image size, cause those that don't work has much bigger size than my view's real estate. Using setBackgroundDrawable() does work, but it also shrinks to the View's real estate size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you get OutOfMemoryError, cause onDraw is called many times during view lifecycle, and every time you are allocating memory for new bitmap. Just make bg member (maybe - static) of your class and load it only once - in your view's constructor. And don't forget to recycle bitmap on view's detaching.

Comment: Well, this happens at the first time, I've put a breakpoint on: bg = BitmapFactory.decode(file); While debugging, exception occurs on g.setBitmap(bg); I get an IllegalStateException, but couldn't retrieve more info about this exception. I'm afraid it has to do with the size or density of bitmap, but my knowledge is limited when it comes to graphics.

Comment: Ok, I found out that bg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file); returns a immutable bitmap, which means I can't draw on it. Can someone please provide me just a simple example how to load an image from a file (or a bytearray) and put it as a background image of a custom View, so I can draw on it in onDraw() handler of the view? Just a simple example, thank you.

Comment: I can propose two ways of making such thing:
1) call internally View.setBackgroundDrawable() (previously you need to create BitmapDrawable from bitmap);
2) call g.drawBitmap() instead of g.setBitmap(). In this case you aren't replace canvas source, but draw into it.

Comment: Yes, thnx, BitmapDrawable did the trick for me. I now have to find out how to show it without scaling etc.. but that's another story, thank you.