# Android: connecting items with lines within gridview

Tags: android, gridview, draw, items

Is there a way to connect items within a GridView with lines / arrows preferably in the background?

I have a dynamic amount of items (buttons) within a GridView and have to connect certain buttons with others depending on data of a database.

The GridView will most likely be larger than the screen so the view containing the lines/arrows will have to scroll with the GridView simultaneously.

[question]: [Android: network relationship graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225735/android-network-relationship-graph) describes my problem in a more detailed way.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, did any answer aid you???

Comment: No I couldn't figure out a solution in time, so I only used the GridView without the background at that time. Now that my exams are over and I actually have to continue working on this again I decided to completely drop this approach, since I could get neither the position nor the size properly. I'll now try to work with a custom SurfaceView and implement my own scrolling and clicking. I just started looking into the matter though.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would think to define a layout to be used as the "background" object of your gridview. The layout would be a single relative layout with a custom view that fills parent in both dimensions.

Within this custom view, I would then override the "onDraw" method and all appropriate constructors to perform your arrow drawing on the singular canvas that should be the exact size now of your gridview!

This is where I would think to begin.

Also look here:

[Draw background of custom View from .png file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015441/draw-background-of-custom-view-from-png-file-on-android)

as it shows how to set the backgroundDrawable of a view. If you implement a custom view as drawable, then you should be able to create a new one and send it into your grid view's background drawable.

To make it scroll along with your actual grid data, you may need to play around a bit with the size of the gridview being the full size of the DataSet you are displaying, and containing that within other scrollviews to get this accomplished.

I do have a gridview in an app of mine, that I implemented a horizontal scrollview (as I have buttons at the top allowing me to sort by any of the columns and want those always to be visible, and the gridview to vertically scroll underneath).  This creates the overall width of the gridview for me as it simply follows the parent width which wraps the content of the linear layout defining the button set at the top. The gridview then auto scrolls in the vertical direction, leaving the higher level horizontal scroller to perform in the horizontal direction. For you, you may need to have a vertical scroller within a horizontal scroller, and allow your gridview to be full size (i.e. larger than the content view area) and allow the outer scrollers to perform the scrolling for you.  This may be the only way to ensure that your background drawable view is the proper size to the table you are trying to display!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I'll look into it. An issue is that I still have to know the positions of the items in order to draw arrows between them.